# How calculate the max area from random point in a MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, polygon, spatial

I have a table with this data  :  x,y column

0 0,1 2,5 2,5 1,2 1       (they are random points)

with this point how can i get the biggest area posible.

Sample:

select   area(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON( (0 0,1 3,5 3,5 1,3 1,0 0) )' )) = 10

select   area(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT( 'POLYGON( (0 0,1 3,5 3,5 1,0 0) )' )) = 11

note: in the table I do not know the best order of the points

Do you have any suggestion ?

Comment: Graham, Jarvis, Kirpatrick, Chan... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks Akina,
I was able to  fix the problem with this CONVEXHULL.

```
select   AREA(ST_CONVEXHULL(ST_GEOMFROMTEXT( 'MultiPoint( 0 0,1 2,5 2,5 1,2 1 )' )))
```